# Can the admin of a SSH server monitor internet traffic?

Tags: ssh, security, openssh

I use SSH Tunnelling + socks4/5 to browse securely, but a certain question came up in my mind, can the administrator of that SSH server monitor my traffic? like see which websites I am visiting, passwords..etc? (also, that SSH server runs on OpenSSH 6.2p2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an admin can practically monitor anything you type. All he would need to install is a keylogger like [logkeys](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/logkeys) and it will store any key you touch. So that includes passwords.

Comment: I got the impression that the OP was using ssh to remote in to the server, so keyloggers would not be in play.. ??